# Efficient combinations of multiple lists (Python)

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to figure out the most efficient way to get a sorted list of combinations of the items of multiple lists (the number is not known beforehand) in Python (3). For example, if I have a list of sublists:

```
a = [[0, 1, 2], [0], [0, 1]]
```

I expect the following output:

```
[(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 2), (0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 2)]
```

At the moment, the best method I have is to use `itertools.product()` to first generate all possible permutations of the three lists, sort the contents of the permutations, then take the set of those items, and then to finally sort that set:

```
tuples = it.product(*a)
tuples_sorted = [tuple(sorted(i)) for i in tuples]
output = sorted(set(tuples_sorted))
```

This works just fine, but I was wondering if there was a more efficient or built-in way of doing this? I can imagine the multiple sorting steps getting really cumbersome for a large number of sublists, or for really long sublists. I'm open to numpy solutions, too.

Comment: Why is there no `(0, 1, 0)` element in the output? Is that because it's a permutation of `(0, 0, 1)`?

Comment: That is correct; I'm looking for all possible combinations, not permutations.

Comment: I don't understand your point about things getting cumbersome for large numbers: doesn't it remain the same three lines of code?

Comment: The code remains the same, but I'm concerned that the sorting steps will get out of hand (in a non-linear way, for instance) for larger sublists and alphabets.

Comment: The fundamental nature of this problem seems complex though.  What part of this algorithm seems unnecessarily complex given the problem itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking for is the sorted Cartesian product of multiple lists. It's done like this:

```
import itertools
>>> a2 = [list(element) for element in itertools.product(*a)]
>>> for i in range(0,len(a2)):
...     aa = a2[i]
...     aa.sort()
...     a2[i] = tuple(aa)
... 
>>> a3=[ii for n,ii in enumerate(a3) if ii not in a2[:n]]
>>> a3
[(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 1), (0, 0, 2), (0, 1, 2)]
```

Adapted from [this Cartesian product answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/533917/12452330) and [this unique list answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24582741/12452330).